# How to disable type casting from interface to class that implements interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

How do I disable casting from interface IFoo to class Bar? Is it even possible?

**Assembly one**

```
public interface IFoo
{
   string Name { get; }
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
   public int SecretValue { get; private set; }
   public string Name     { get; private set; }
}
```

**Assembly two**

```
public class Bar : Foo
{
   private IFoo secretFoo;
}
```

Can I prevent Bar from casting secretFoo to type Bar and thus accessing the value of SecretValue?

Comment: SecretValue is public Bar can access SecretValue property in any case. I couldnt understand your question

Comment: You mean you want to prevent casting from `IFoo` to `Foo`, right? You can't access `SecretValue` even if you casted to `Bar`.

Comment: You can make it `internal get`

Comment: @Simonare I would do that, however I need the value of SecretValue in a third assembly.

Comment: I dont think you can do that. Even microsoft has intenal assemblies which are visible to us but in their comments they are advising not to be used by end users.

Comment: Look for private assemblies https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sbscs/about-private-assemblies-

Answer (score 1):

Change `Bar`'s base class from `Foo` to `IFoo`, and property `secretFoo` from type `IFoo` to `Foo`.

```
public class Bar : IFoo
{
    private Foo secretFoo;
    public string Name {
        get
        {
            return secretFoo.Name;
        }
    }
}
```